# Meteor how to access different documents in a form

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a simple form that uses a couple different helpers :

```
<select class="form-control">
    {{#each openTables}}
        <option>Table {{tableNumber}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
<select id="working-servers" class="form-control">
    {{#each workingServers}}
        <option>{{name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
<input id="num-of-guests-select" type="text" value="" name="num-of-guests-select">
```

`openTables` and `workingServers` are global helpers that access different collections

```
Template.registerHelper('openTables', () => {
    let openTables = CurrentTables.find({occupied : false});
    if(openTables) {
        return openTables;
    }
})
Template.registerHelper('workingServers', () => {
    let servers = Servers.find({working : true});
    if(servers) {
        return servers;
    }
});
```

My question is basically : I am trying to update a document in that `CurrentTables` collection with the information from the form.

```
Template.newTableModal.events({
    'click #sendTable' : function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

    }
});
```

In that event function, how do I access the data context of those select boxes? For example,

```
{{#each workingServers}}
<option>{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

each of the objects in `workingServers` has an ID that I want to be able to access in that event function :

`CurrentTables.update(tableId?, {$set: {"serverId" : ??, "currentGuests" : ??}});`

How do I access those documents in relation to the document in the form when I make it? Rather, how do I get that `serverId` from the document selected in that `workingServers` loop.

Is there a better way to do this kind of thing because I need to be able to do similar forms in the future? I mean I know I *could* take the name value ,
`$("#working-servers").val()` and look up in the `Servers` collection to find the ID that matches but that seems really bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

`value` is the returned value when selected, the text part inside the tag is the displayed value. 
So, use your id in `value` and that's what you'll get when selecting

```
{{#each workingServers}}
<option value={{serverId}}>{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```